# Regular expression which matches a URL and return desired value

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I need regular expression which matches a URL and return the desired value

Example (if the URL matches to)

```
1. http://example.com/amp 
2. http://example.com/amp/
3. http://example.com/amp~
```

THEN

it should return: `?amp=1`

ELSE

it should return: `false`

Comment: With regex expressions you can filter strings but as far as I know you cannot add new characters to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `preg_replace` to append `?amp=` to the end of a matching string. Its functionality already does the `if`/`else` functional you require,

> If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged or NULL if an error occurred.

(or I misread the `it should return noting`)

-http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Something like

```
amp\K( |\/|~)$
```

Should do it

```
$string = 'http://example.com/amp~';
echo preg_replace('/amp\K( |\/|~)$/', '$1?amp=1', $string);
```

The `$1` is optional, not sure if you wanted the found character included or not.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/780432

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/JgcrLu/1/

`$` is the end of the string. `()` is a capturing and alteration group. `|`s are alterations. `\K` skips the previously matched regex part.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the programming language you're using but you probably need something like:

**php**:

```
$new = preg_replace('%/amp\b(?:/|~)?%si', '/?amp=1', $old);
```

**python**:

```
new_string = re.sub(r"/amp\b(?:/|~)?", "/?amp=1", old_string, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XUZ02r/1)

Comment: Actually, I am using WordPress plugin "safe redirect manager" which supports regular expression. So, I need to redirect the urls having amp at the end of the URL to a new URL by adding ?amp at the end.

Comment: Thank you @chris85 for correcting me. I meant, if it matches either of the example then it should prefix ?amp=1. Looks like the developer of the Safe redirect manager is not active on Wordpress forum . Could you help me out with this ?